Okay to drill into concrete ceiling with cracks?
I am not too handy. I have a shed-like room in my house that is basically bare cinderblocks I want to use as a workshop/garden tools etc. There is one electrical outlet. I want to hang a work light in there on the ceiling, and then put organizers on the walls. I plan to use concrete screws.
There problem is that my concrete ceiling is starting to crack, probably water damage from before I moved in. Is it safe or might I be asking for a face full of concrete?



Being an unreasonable person, I'll attempt to answer the question without all the information requsted in the comments. Plan on locating a crack free space on the ceiling to mount your work light. I doubt a few 5/32" holes and 1.25" Tapcons will bring the ceiling down. I've installed hundreds of them in slabs for lighting and electrical conduits without having all the design and current physical characteristics. The same goes for the cinder block walls. You might want screws a bit longer depending on the depth of the organizers.

JACK, what sort of buildings were these? I suspect that they weren't random "shed like rooms". This seems dangerously speculative to me. I've studied the Florida condo collapse in some detail, and this smacks of that.

@isherwood With all due respect, and I do respect your knowledge and experience, your comment to me greatly varies from your comment (now deleted) on the original post where you said you doubted a few holes would bring down the ceiling.  I was at the Florida condo collapse site for two days immediately following the collapse, working with the power company and no one believed a few 5/32" holes brought down the building. :-)

I wasn't referring to the screws. I was referring to the cracks and the fact that we know so little about this structure. I find it funny how the sky is falling for so many people if a joist has a nick in it, but this doesn't faze us.
